# sed extract substring inclusive of pattern

Tags: bash, shell

I have below command to extract a substring from a string but it is excluding the patterns, can you please help.

```
echo ". ~/.bash_profile ; /home/script/sample.sh >> ~/log/sample.log" | sed -e 's/.*\/home\(.*\)sh.*/\1/'
```

Result: `/script/sample`

But I want the result to be `/home/script/sample.sh`

Comment: I think something formatted when I posted here. command is echo ". ~/.bash_profile ; /home/script/sample.sh >> ~/log/sample.log" | sed -e 's/.*\/home\(.*\)sh.*/\1/'

Comment: We're helpful that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is anything inside the capturing group `\(..\)`, so just extend that around the whole piece you want:

```
echo ". ~/.bash_profile ; /home/script/sample.sh >> ~/log/sample.log" |
    sed -e 's/.*\(\/home.*sh\).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

In case your string `/home/script/sample.sh` coming always on same place then you could simply try:

```
echo ". ~/.bash_profile ; /home/script/sample.sh >> ~/log/sample.log" | cut -d' ' -f4
/home/script/sample.sh
```

In case you are ok with `awk` try following, irrespective of place of string `home` it will match regex and print it.

```
echo ". ~/.bash_profile ; /home/script/sample.sh >> ~/log/sample.log" | awk 'match($0,/\/home.*\.sh/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

Comment: @Jazz, could you please try this solution once too and let me know.

Comment: Thanks, but the position for the script is not fixed, hence this doesn't help.

Comment: @Jazz, Sure, I have added a generic solution now with `awk`, please do let me know in case of any queries.